# setVisibility only works randomly

Tags: android, textview, constraints

I have a really weird problem where the `setVisibility()` function works in one part of the code, but in the other it doesn't even though they are the exact same.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView verifyMsg = findViewById(R.id.verifyEmailMessage);

        ImageView bottomPlayer = findViewById(R.id.bottomPlayer);
        if((((ServiceState) this.getApplication()).isRunning())){
            bottomPlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            bottomPlayer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        if(!fAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()){
            verifyMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ...
```

The first if statement gets triggered and doesn't change the visibility at all. When second when gets triggered it suddenly gets triggered. So the Textviews visibility gets changed but the imageviews doesn't. Am I being extremely stupid or what did I do wrong?! No logcat error btw. Here is also my xml file:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <TextView
             android:id="@+id/verifyEmailMessage"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
             android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
             android:text="Bitte bestätigen sie die Email"
             android:textAlignment="center"
             android:textStyle="bold"
             android:visibility="gone"
             app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#111111"
        android:id="@+id/bottomPlayer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView">

    </ImageView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I don't know what to do anymore. This problem is stupid.

EDIT: since the problem seems to lie somewhere else: here is my whole class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setWifiLock();

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = 
        findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,  
        R.id.fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);

        createNotificationChanel();
        FirebaseAuth fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //AlertDialog.Builder resetAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        TextView verifyMsg = findViewById(R.id.verifyEmailMessage);
        Button verifyBtn = findViewById(R.id.verifyEmailBtn);

        ImageView bottomPlayer = findViewById(R.id.bottomPlayer);
        if((((ServiceState) this.getApplication()).isRunning())){
            bottomPlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            bottomPlayer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        if(!fAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()){

            verifyBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            verifyMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new 
            NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, "lemubitA")
             .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_message_24)
             .setContentTitle("Bitte bestätige deine Email")
             .setContentText("- Schmitties Technik Freunde")
             .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = 
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
 
            notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());

        }

        verifyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
 fAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new 
 OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bestägungsemail wurde 
                        gesendet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        verifyBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        verifyMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

    private void setWifiLock() {

        WifiManager.WifiLock wifilock = ((WifiManager) 
        getApplicationContext()
        .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
        .createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "mylock");
        wifilock.acquire();

    }


    private void createNotificationChanel(){

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            CharSequence name = "BaywatchBerlin";
            String description = "Mit Klaas Heufer Umlauf";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new 
            NotificationChannel("lemubitA", name, importance);
            notificationChannel.setDescription(description);
            notificationChannel.setSound(null, null);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = 
            getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: what do you want to verify and why are you using Visible on both statements

Comment: why you are calling if(true) it will be always true ... you can directly call it's content

Comment: @AgentP edited my comment it probably was about to minimalistic. I actually want to display a bottom mediaplayer as footer when the mediaplayer is running. The statements work fine so i replaced them with true. For debug purposes i exchanged the ImageView with the textview i have a couple lines later but it didn't work either. Hope that explains it a bit better.

Comment: so basically you are expecting verifyMsg to be visible. But it's not happening am I correct?

Comment: @AgentP No i am expecting bottomPlayer to be invisible when the app starts because ((ServiceState) this.getApplication()).isRunning() returns false because the mediaplayer isn't running.

Comment: Are you sure (((ServiceState) this.getApplication()).isRunning()) this line returning true ? and Have you written the ServiceState class ? by yourself?

Comment: Yes i already checked that. It returns true trust me. This isn't the problem. Somehow the setVisibility doesn't do anything for some reason. That's why i first put if(true) in the question which was a bit dumb

Comment: In that case we need more code the code is not just sufficient. There might be some other line which might be toggling the visibility of the imageview later. your current code is just fine to make that image visible for now

Comment: @AgentP alright thanks for the help!!! I really appreciate it :) I provided the whole class in the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: @AgentP please see my updated answer

Comment: Not a problem :) I am very happy that you found the solution for the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found the problem: I haven't provided it in my question since I thought it didn't matter. This is the code where the `setVisibility` doesn't work

```
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_activity);
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

ImageView bottomPlayer = findViewById(R.id.bottomPlayer);
if((((ServiceState) this.getApplication()).isRunning())){
    bottomPlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.fragment,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
    R.id.bottomPlayer,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
} else {
    bottomPlayer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.fragment,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
    R.id.bottomNavigationView,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
}
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

and this is the one where it works:

```
ImageView bottomPlayer = findViewById(R.id.bottomPlayer);
if((((ServiceState) this.getApplication()).isRunning())){
    bottomPlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    bottomPlayer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

The `ConstraintSet` is what prohibiting the `setVisibility`. Any ideas??

There may be an easier approach but i just disjointed the two functions and now it works fine:

```
ImageView bottomPlayer = findViewById(R.id.bottomPlayer);
        if((((ServiceState) this.getApplication()).isRunning())){
            bottomPlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            bottomPlayer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_activity);
        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
        if((((ServiceState) this.getApplication()).isRunning())){
            constraintSet.connect(R.id.fragment,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,R.id.bottomPlayer,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
        } else {
            constraintSet.connect(R.id.fragment,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,R.id.bottomNavigationView,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
        }
        constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```